# SetText is not working for TextView. In my code textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue)); is giving error as error: <identifier> expected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

```
package com.example.menewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.menewapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            TextView textValue = findViewById(R.id.text_value);
            String stringvalue = textValue.getText().toString();
            int old = Integer.parseInt(stringvalue);
            int newValue = MyNewWorker.doubleTheValue(old);
            textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "old " + old + "is changed to " + newValue, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

SetText is not working for TextView. In my code textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue)); is giving error as error:  expected. Please help me. textValue.getText is working but textValue.setText is not. i am new to android application development and not getting clue on how to solve this

Comment: error coming as error: <identifier> expected
            textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));

Comment: Put TextView textValue = findViewById(R.id.text_value); on the onCreate() method, not on the click listener

Comment: Hi Javdromero, still giving same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code that reads and manipulates the text_value should be included in the **onClick()** method that is inside the **OnClickListener()**

```
    binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView textValue = findViewById(R.id.text_value);
            String stringValue = textValue.getText().toString();
            int originalValue = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
            int newValue = MyWorker.doubleTheValue(originalValue);
            textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));
            Snackbar.make(view, "old " + old + "is changed to " + newValue, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

I came across this exact problem while going through the Pluralsight course *Understanding Android Applications*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Integer.toString(newValue)`  use `String.valueOf()`

```
textValue.setText(String.valueOf(newValue))
```

Comment: Issue is with setText and not integer to string.